# Laravel 5.1 detach with where

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want detach without some records

my role_user table is    id | role_id | user_id

```
<?php

   $user->roles()->detach();
?>
```

I don't want detach all records some records need (I mean find solution to where clause inside detach() ). How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finnaly I found the solution

```
$user->roles()->wherePivot('role_id', '!=', 3)->detach();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sync and pass in the array of ids you dont want delete.
The inverse is to use detach and pass in an array of ids you want to delete.